# How to detect reactions on a DM message? -DSharpPlus

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

Recently, I have been trying to learn C# and doing so I am using a DSharpPlus to make a Discord Bot. My plan with this bot was to do alot of things, but one of the main things was to create a way to ensure everyone in my server "Agree's to the rules". I wanted this to look good so I put together a DiscordEmbed and started playing around with ways I could use Interactivity in this API. I wanted to send a message directly to the user (DMChannel) asking them if they accept the rules using reactions `yesReaction & noReaction`. I have tried many ways but for some reason I can't get the `WaitForReactionAsync()` to continue once a reaction is made. Below is a snippet of my code.

**General Question:** Is this possible and If so what am I doing wrong because this works in my guild on normal channels.

```
        public async Task<Task> OnMemberJoin(GuildMemberAddEventArgs e)
        {
            var thumbnail = new EmbedThumbnail { Url = e.Client.CurrentUser.AvatarUrl, };
            var rulesEmbed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder
            {
                Title = "Do you accept these rules?",
                Description = "By accepting these rules you agree that if any of the above are broken, it could/will result in a perm ban from G Hub.",
                Thumbnail = thumbnail,
                Color = DiscordColor.Red,
            };

            var message = await e.Member.SendMessageAsync(embed: rulesEmbed);

            var yesEmoji = DiscordEmoji.FromName(e.Client, ":white_check_mark:");
            var noEmoji = DiscordEmoji.FromName(e.Client, ":x:");

            await Task.Delay(1000);

            await message.CreateReactionAsync(yesEmoji);
            await message.CreateReactionAsync(noEmoji);

            await Task.Delay(1000);
            var interactivity = e.Client.GetInteractivity();
            var reactionResult = await interactivity.WaitForReactionAsync(x => 
                x.Message == message, 
                e.Member,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
            );

            if (reactionResult.TimedOut)
            {
                var reactionMember = e.Member;
                await e.Guild.BanMemberAsync(reactionMember, 0, "Kicked for declining Rules.");
                await e.Guild.UnbanMemberAsync(e.Member);
                await message.DeleteAsync();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            if (reactionResult.Result.Emoji == yesEmoji)
            {
                //Guest Role
                var role = e.Guild.GetRole(742143094761324565);
                var roleMember = e.Member;
                await roleMember.GrantRoleAsync(role);
                await message.DeleteAsync();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            else if (reactionResult.Result.Emoji == noEmoji)
            {
                var role = e.Guild.GetRole(742143094761324565);
                var roleMember = e.Member;
                if (roleMember.Roles.Contains(role))
                {
                    await roleMember.RevokeRoleAsync(role);
                    await e.Guild.BanMemberAsync(roleMember, 0, "Kicked for declining Rules.");
                    await e.Guild.UnbanMemberAsync(roleMember);
                    await message.DeleteAsync();
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            else
            {
                var role = e.Guild.GetRole(742143094761324565);
                var roleMember = e.Member;
                await roleMember.RevokeRoleAsync(role);
                await e.Guild.BanMemberAsync(roleMember, 0, "Kicked for using different emoji in Accepting Rules.");
                await e.Guild.UnbanMemberAsync(roleMember);
                await message.DeleteAsync();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note: You dont need to return a task in a task. Your return type can just be `Task` which means you wont need to return `Task.CompletedTask`. Obviously if you want it to return at that point, you keep the `return;`

Comment: Thanks, I thought so, just didn't want to screw up anything knowing I know very little about C#.

Answer (score 0):

`e.Member` won't work in DMs. Use e.Message.Author instead.

```
var reactionResult = await interactivity.WaitForReactionAsync(x => 
            x.Message == message, 
            e.Message.Author,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `DiscordClient.UseInteractivity()` after creating a bot, like this

```
var discord = new DiscordClient();

discord.UseInteractivity(new InteractivityConfiguration() 
{ 
    PollBehaviour = PollBehaviour.KeepEmojis,
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
});
```